# Listen and react to keypresses while another process is running?

Tags: bash, unix, terminal, console, tty

I have this nifty couple of lines in my .bashrc that clears my unix terminal when I press shift+alt+c:

```
alias cls='printf "\033c"'
bind -x '"\eC":"cls"'
```

However, as you could probably guess, it only works when I'm actually at the prompt. If I'm in the middle of a program such as, let's say, tail -f, then I have to get back to the prompt, press shift+alt+c, then go back to the program (or ctrl+z, shift+alt+c, then fg).

I'm thinking it would be cool if I could somehow listen for keys while this other program is running. It's probably impossible, but I figured I'd ask here before I gave up. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not going to work. That's your shell doing that.

Your shell isn't active when something else is.

You could do this sort of thing with your terminal if you really wanted to though (assuming it allows you to control it sufficiently) since your terminal sees the keys first.